# jQuery: JSON api is not working

Tags: jquery

I'm having a issue to get my twitter status to work properly. If you go to http://www.nascarspeedpark.com/nc.aspx and look at the right side of the page you'll see latest tweets.  The link next to the Avatar is not working.

The code looks right to me. It seems as though the code is calling the twitter api properly.

```
function relative_time(date) {
  var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
  var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - date) / 1000, 10);
  var r = '';
  if (delta < 60) {
    r = delta + ' seconds ago';
  } else if(delta < 120) {
    r = 'a minute ago';
  } else if(delta < (45*60)) {
    r = (parseInt(delta / 60, 10)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
  } else if(delta < (2*60*60)) {
    r = 'an hour ago';
  } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
    r = '' + (parseInt(delta / 3600, 10)).toString() + ' hours ago';
  } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
    r = 'a day ago';
  } else {
    r = (parseInt(delta / 86400, 10)).toString() + ' days ago';
  }
  return 'about ' + r;
}

function build_url() {
  var proto = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:');
  var count = (s.fetch === null) ? s.count : s.fetch;
  if (s.list) {
    return proto+"//"+s.twitter_api_url+"/1/"+s.username[0]+"/lists/"+s.list+"/statuses.json?per_page="+count+"&callback=?";
  } else if (s.favorites) {
    return proto+"//"+s.twitter_api_url+"/favorites/"+s.username[0]+".json?count="+s.count+"&callback=?";
  } else if (s.query === null && s.username.length == 1) {
    return proto+'//'+s.twitter_api_url+'/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+s.username[0]+'&count='+count+(s.retweets ? '&include_rts=1' : '')+'&callback=?';
  } else {
    var query = (s.query || 'from:'+s.username.join(' OR from:'));
    return proto+'//'+s.twitter_search_url+'/search.json?&q='+encodeURIComponent(query)+'&rpp='+count+'&callback=?';
  }
}
```

Comment: The link next to the avatar is working perfectly for me.

Comment: You mean the 'about an hour ago' link?  Cuz I get a 404 on twitter, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Hey buddy, that's odd for me if when I click on the about 2 days ago or what ever link it keeps taking me to a error page. for example http://screencast.com/t/vSlJBTGf4IQI

Comment: @Groovetrain yes the hour ago link is not working for me.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish here, maybe there is another way to go about this?

Comment: @cfarm54, i'm just trying to get the tweets to display on the site and when you click on the link that displays the when the last tweet was made go to the proper status url.

Comment: for example when the user clicks on that link it goes to the tweet that was made like so: http://twitter.com/seaofclouds/status/53538695428571136

Comment: not sure i fully understand but shouldn't it be a simple copy/paste from the twitter widget example?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem is that your script is getting (and thus linking to) the wrong tweet id. For example, the latest tweet id is `53522381905461248` but for some reason, your script gets the value `53522381905461250` through `item.id`. The JSON response from twitter seems to be alright but the parsed JSON object seems to get the wrong value for `id`.

Where you create the HTML for the relative time linked to the Twitter status page, Try using the `id_str` property instead:

```
var date = '<span class="tweet_time"><a href="http://twitter.com/'+from_user+'/statuses/'+item.id_str+'" title="view tweet on twitter">'+relative_time(item.created_at)+'</a></span>';
```

Comment: So, something like this:  var time ="http://"+s.twitter_url+"/"+screen_name+"/status/"+item.id_str;

Comment: @Kmack Yes, simply replace use of `item.id` with `item.id_str`. As far as I can tell from debugging the script on that page you linked to, the `id_str` value was not affected by whatever bug is causing the `id` value to be incremented.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for there help. I got it working.  http://www.nascarspeedpark.com/nc.aspx

Comment: @Kmack Was this the solution then? If so, please consider marking it as the answer. If not, please consider adding a new answer to this question yourself and marking *it* as the answer.